# Alternatives to hard-coding user passwords in SQL script

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Let's say you have a script with a bunch of `ALTER USER <username> IDENTIFIED BY <password>;` commands to change user passwords in an Oracle db (12c), and you'd like to implement something to hide or encrypt the passwords.

I tried to wrap the sql script, but that didn't work since it is not a database package.

What is the best alternative to achieve this?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Or you can expire the password and let the user enter their password during the subsequent login?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your quick replies.

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestions won't work for me.  @zaph not sure how those functions would help me alter db users passwords.

Comment: @JSapkota the db user accounts I'm altering are not assigned to a person. They are accounts used by Oracle applications to perform back-end tasks. I need to change the passwords every time I refresh a non-production database from a dump of the production one.

Comment: If passwords or keys are saved to disk they are a security risk when the system is successfully attacked. If you don't believe there will ever be a successful attack then there is no reason to encrypt anything, right? The solution is to use an HSM (ah the cost of security) where the encrypting keys are never available, lacking that setup an encryption server with minimal access and no Internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can interrogate (existing) password hash values from database:

```
SELECT NAME AS USERNAME, PASSWORD, spare4 AS PW_HASH
FROM sys.user$
WHERE TYPE# = 1;
```

You can generate a secure script like this:

```
SELECT 'ALTER USER '||NAME||' IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '''||spare4||';'||PASSWORD||''';' AS cmd
FROM sys.user$
WHERE TYPE# = 1
   AND spare4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Note, in older releases the Oracle password was not case sensitive but those passwords are still supported as long as they are not modified. For those records `SPARE4` attribute is NULL. However, since you can query only existing (i.e. modified) passwords this should not apply for your situation.

I use this approach to automatically synchronize user passwords from production database to test database, it is working fine for years.

Answer (score 1):

I would first consider using an authentication method other than the database, to be honest.

Broadly speaking, the choices are:

1. Operating system
2. Network (SSL/3rd Party etc)
3. OAS (LDAP)

More information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#i1007520

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the file (e.g. with [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL)). Save only the encrypted file to the version control system (you're using a version control system, right ?).

Below you'll see an OpenSSL encryption/decryption example. You can automate the process with a scripting to fit better to your workflow. Note that instead of manually typing the encryption password you can also use `-pass` command line argument (see PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS in `man 1 openssl` for the details).

```
$ cat /tmp/script.sql 
alter user batman identified by darknight;
alter user robin identified by wonderboy;
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -base64 -salt -in /tmp/script.sql -out /tmp/script.enc
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
$ rm /tmp/script.sql 
$ cat /tmp/script.enc 
U2FsdGVkX1/R71mmmadUXTrFz2G6TW5KQmivuxoE1UbjcRGCgw5bAQLGcGspxubx
wXkk8/rrwoPdysiULOgzB3yikuTMf8kFvLUBr0+QxE50Vs3iBaderelVJ9ZN9chv
0zBbISq2M5z47xFA6JIeDg==
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -base64 -salt -in /tmp/script.enc -out /tmp/script.sql
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
$ cat /tmp/script.sql 
alter user batman identified by darknight;
alter user robin identified by wonderboy;
$
```

Comment: that would encrypt the file, but I won't be able to run the encrypted version via SQL*Plus.

Comment: @Beto Err ... You decrypt the file before running it with sqlplus and delete the decrypted file after the run ? Wrap all that with your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use prompt like this

`alter user robin identified by &password;`

So when you run the script it get prompt to ask you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it  is a script with a long number of different passwords... Manually entering them every time I run the script would be painful.